# How do I deploy CodeIgniter on Laravel Forge?

Tags: codeigniter, laravel-forge

I want to deploy Codeigniter the on Laravel Forge platform, because I love the simplicity and auto-deploy nature of the platform.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, and the problems I had doing it.

**Problem 1**
Because forge runs on Nginx, not apache, any Apache PHP directives will be ignored. (I think). So, the main problem I had was that the [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive in the default configuration is set to 'Off', meaning this PHP FPM CONFIGURATION

**Problem 2**

In the Nginx configuration file specific to the site (not the server) replace

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

With

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

Comment: I haven't bought Forge yet, and I can't find any information on how would I trigger the deploy once the build passes on my CI server, how did you do that? do you call a **wget** url like this post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/envoyer/envoyer-ci-testing-a-laravel-5-application-and-triggering-deployment-with-codeship ?

Comment: I emailed Taylor, inventor of forge, who said it's just a bash script

Comment: They have a deployment trigger URL that you use. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This configuration definitely works for Codeigniter on Laravel Forge in May 2019

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name default;




root /home/forge/default/;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
# ssl_certificate;
# ssl_certificate_key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'REPLACE WITH YOURS';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

#added tto try to get around the 'no input file specified' error
autoindex on;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/default/server/*;

location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}